# When my location is turned on can someone track me?

Tags: android, user-tracking, geolocation

When the location is turned on can someone track me without me sharing my location with them?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? If your location is shared without you allowing it to be shared (i.e. without giving an app permission), that would be a bug in the software. GPS itself is passive, so you can use it without having to share information with others.

Comment: You might want to narrow it down from "someone" to a specific set. e.g., Friends/Family? Random strangers? ISPs? Some Author whose app you have installed on your device?

Comment: Of course the OP knows best but I interpret this as asking what safeguards are in place to ensure that location service information is restricted to the intended recipients, and how realistic is it for them to be circumvented.

Comment: 'Someone' in this context probably means an ex-boyfriend or something along those lines. A possibly tech-savvy individual that is threatening. The answer is: if he / she's clever enough to infect the phone, GPS can be turned on remotely so it doesn't matter. Without infecting the phone  or sending a location-asking webpage there's no common way.

Comment: So the short answer is: do NOT click on a webpage asking you to share your location. That's how i would do it. But you're already on the lookout so that's probably not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sort of contradicts itself, because by turning your location ON, you are sharing your location. By sharing your location, you are making it a lot easier for this "someone" to be able track you. I suggest if you are woried about being tracked you start by turning off your location, or if you are really paranoid, then there are other methods of working with GPS and location.

**Digital Location Security**

**VPN:**

For starters you can use a **VPN** to hide your digital location when using the Internet. You can find a lot of them on Android (One example could be `OpenVPN`). This will help with anyone tracking you through the internet.

**Tor:**

Another way to help you hide yourself on the internet would be using Tor. On mobile devices, Tor Service is actually called "Orbot". You can also get "Orfox" which is like the Tor Browser (Firefox). But again this will only help you hide yourself on the internet.

**Physical Location Security**

This phase is used when you think "someone" is trying to physically track you down from the location of your device.

**GPS jamming and blocking devices**

- **GPS jamming gadgets** – Commonly sold online, popular models simply plug into a vehicle’s 12v adapter (similar to the one in [THIS](http://i1.wp.com/gpssystems.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/gps-jammer-blocker.jpg?w=300) picture) and interfere with any GPS radio signal within a range of about 30ft.
- **Metal shields** – A cheaper, non-powered option is wrapping the device in a metal sleeve such as brass mesh or a lead camera film protector. It has been reported that car thieves have been known to transport stolen cars fitted with GPS tracking units inside refrigerated trucks to block the GPS signal.
- **GPS spoofing gadgets** – These gadgets can send a fake radio signal that overrides the signal being transmitted by the GPS device and reports a fake location. These are not only illegal but can be dangerous to other GPS users, particularly those used in commercial transportation.
- **Mobile phone jammers** – Many GPS devices report real-time tracking, which uses a wireless carrier to communicate this information to the person doing the tracking. A cell phone jammer can be used to block the signal being transmitted to the wireless carrier preventing status updates being sent. Unlike a GPS jammer this also prevents mobile phone use.

**Resources**

You can learn more about GPS and wireless signals with the link below:

http://gpssystems.net/gps-jamming/

and remember...You can never be 100% invisible from "someone", however, you can make it more difficult for "someone" to locate you digitally, and physically using some of these steps above.

Comment: "Your question sort of contradicts itself, because by turning your location ON, you are sharing your location." - How does using GPS imply that you're sharing your position?

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume from the question and your profile, that you are an average user of Android, who wants to learn a bit about technology.

1. It is important to know, what are your aims, to be able to help you to achieve it. Do you wish to be not tracked?
2. When you turn on your location sharing, you are allowing the phone to "officially" share its location directly with other applications. You can chose to turn it off, but it does not necessarily mean, that noone can see where is your phone, or you personally.
   There are other legal or not legal ways to follow your "online" activity. If you want to hide the location of the phone from an average user there are few ways to do it, if you have all the abilities (the owner of the phone). If you want to hide your activity from corporations or higher authorities, it will demand higher levels of technical knowledge. There are many ways to circumvent these blockings. Practically it does not matter if your phone is turned on at all to track you, because the main function of a mobile phone is to find it anywhere to be able to be communicate with it.