# Strange spam to my IG and email with my secret information

Tags: malware, android, spam, spyware, trojan

I got strange email recently telling that i have an affair and it listed my visited cities with my boyfriend last year. Also threaten to share my relationship with others. Something that bother me that I do not share my trips to others and it list down all the cities I visited. I have checked that I do not keep my itineraries but recently submitted my scan of my passports to online visa lodgement of oz.

I am frustrated why it knew my details like spying me? And it sends the email to my office email.

Previously I receive the same threatening message and comments in my instagram. And I put the IG story telling it is a "spambot attack" and then a strange account occured and tag me and others that it is not a spambot attack and keep posting and tagging me having an affair.

I had checked the story who viewed the story, no strange accounts vieweing it.

Is it possible that my phone is being spied? And what is the logic behind listing my visited cities?

Really frustrated and afraid for next attack and how to stop this? Two times attack in two different accounts telling the same story. For information currently i use oppo.

**More information**

The spam in instagram and email is using well constructed english. I am from a country that english is not primary language, maybe only people educated overseas can speak that kind of english.

In the instagram post that telling me its not attack, it refer me as my account name e.q @myaccount not my name

In the email it opened the email with Hi there, and then followed by english introductory and list down the countries using ordered list.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure if any one of the following is the case or not but I will try to suggest you many possible cases:

- **Your Gmail account :**
  One might find it amusing how much user data Google services log and use for providing various features. Try to remember if you had ever forgotten to log out from your gmail account when you had used it on a device not exactly yours or less trustworthy. If so you should immediately go to Google account security tab and check your logins and log yourself out of all the unknown sessions.
- **Your mobile phone :**
  Attackers or those who use smart tools such as `metasploit` etc. can create a payload app and use some social engineering skills to install it on target device. These apps are surprisingly strong enough to track your geographic locations and other such critical details. You should check your `oppo` phone's installed apps and find out those apps which are suspicious and uninstall them after finding details. *Do not think that there are only those apps which are visible in the menu of your phone.*
- **Social media check-ins :**
  Now this might sound funny but there are people who are so obsessed with instantly updating their statuses and check-ins on `social media` such as `Facebook` ,`Instagram`, etc. Make sure you are not one of them and remove unknown people from your friend list, maybe the one who is attacking you is one of them.
- **A close person to you :**
  Don't just deny this entirely based on your affection for your close people. Many a times there are people who do this just to scare you out and with no serious bad intention like a prank or some sort of that stuff. Make sure this is not the case with you.
  [Further reading 1](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/phone-stalking.htm) 
  [Further reading 2](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/your-smartphone-can-be-tracked-even-if-gps-location-services-are-turned-off/) 
  [Further reading 3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166905/when-my-location-is-turned-on-can-someone-track-me)